# Problem with proof of theorem of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Hi guys i have a problem with a proof of theorem.

Theorem 2:Be  $D\in\mathbb{R}$  y $f:\;D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Continuous  inyective, then the function inverse of $f$, $f^{-1}:\;f(D)\rightarrow D$ defined how $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ is Continuous.

That's the proof

Proof: We know $f:\;D\rightarrow F(D)$ is biyective, then for prove $f^{-1}$ is continuous only we need prove $f(V)$ is open set, where $V$ is an subset open of $D$. (for other theorem). Be $V\subset D$ then $V^{c}$ is closed. $D$ is compact, then $V^{c}$ is compact. then $f(V^{c})$ is compact(for theorem) as $f$ is inyective, we have $f(V^{c})=f(V)^{c}$ is closed, then $f(V)$ is open.

Now, the proof is fine?

Comment: You seem to use that $D$ is compact - but is it?

Comment: Note that for $D=(-1,0]\cup [1,2)$ and $f(x)=|x|$, we have that $f$ is injective and continuous and $f(D)=[0,2)$. But the inverse function $[0,2)\to (-1,0]\cup [1,2)$ is not continuous